# Trying "simple" parsing w/ antlr4 to reformat / pretty-print

Tags: regex, antlr4, pretty-print, parentheses

Scenario:

- I receive a mystery language with obviously very deep syntax

  - Enormous 10k mess, on a single line, represents 1 statement in mystery language
  - Suppose I don't initially care about the deep syntax
- All I want to do is reformat it based, on nested parenthesis

My simplified language Rules:

- Most of the text I don't care about, I just want to preserve it as-is
- Opening paren means open a new level; matching closing paren means done with that level
- Can have multiple parenthesis at same level separated by commas, though I don't really care about that
- Can have multiple adjacent opening and closing parenthesis
- There may or may not be text before the first paren, and after the last paren

I've tried a bunch of different grammars, starting with the ArrayInit example in the Antlr 4 Reference book.

This is one failed attempt:

```
grammar NestedParens ;
init: STR* ( '(' value (value)* ')' )* STR* ;
value: init
     | STR
     ;
STR: [^()]+ ;
```

The error ANTLR gives:

> "error(153): NestedParens.g4:5:0: rule init contains a closure with at least one alternative that can match an empty string"

*(line number might be off from what I posted)*

A few thoughts:

- I think the valid zero-length strings are an issue, but not sure how to factor around them
- Maybe Antlr, which I believe is always top-down, isn't the right tool for this?
- Maybe there's an easier tool that lets you only specify that you care about matching parens, braces, brackets, etc?

Comment: How does your attempt fail? Can you provide  example input with corresponding output? Do parenthesis always denote the start/end of a level, no parenthesis inside comments or string literals? If there are no string literals and comments, then I wouldn't bother with a parser generator but just simply write a few lines of code that keep track of the level and emit some indentation where needed.

Comment: @BartKiers that example grammar isn't accepted and says "error(153): NestedParens.g4:5:0: rule init contains a closure with at least one alternative that can match an empty string" (line number might be off from what I posted)  Since it doesn't accept it, there's not input to try.  Will answer your other question in separate comment.

Comment: @BartKiers yes, an open parent always indicates a new level, and a close paren always closes it.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not attached to the example code I posted, I'm looking for anything that would work.  But in the past, if you don't post an example on stack, people ask for it.  In reality I've probably got a half dozen completely wrong attempts, didn't see the point in posting them, just more noise.

Comment: No, I mean some example input you're trying to parse with the corresponding pretty-printed output. But since your language is so simple, again, I wouldn't bother with a parser generator at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this grammar:

```
grammar NestedParens ;
init: STR* ( '(' value (value)* ')' ) STR* ;
value: init
     | STR
     ;
STR: [^()]+ ;
```

The difference is one missing `*` which made the empty string matching `init` in your version (the error that the antlr compiler complained about) no longer match.

This would also work:

```
grammar NestedParens ;
init: STR* ( '(' value (value)* ')' )+ STR* ;
value: init
     | STR
     ;
STR: [^()]+ ;
```